# Finding the longest alphabetical substring in a longer string

Tags: python, string, alphabetical

This code finds the longest alphabetical substring in a string (`s`).

```
letter = s[0]      
best = ''          
for n in range(1, len(s)):    
    if len(letter) > len(best):
        best = letter
    if s[n] >= s[n-1]:
        letter += s[n]    
    else:                      
        letter = s[n]
```

It works most of the time, but occasionally it gives wrong answers and I am confused why it only works sometimes. for example when:

> s='maezsibmhzxhpprvx'

It said the answer was "hpprv" while it should have been "hpprvx".

In another case, when

> s='ysdxvkctcpxidnvaepz'

It gave the answer "cpx", when it should have been "aepz".

Can anyone make sense of why it does this?

Comment: Your code runs perfectly fine and has the expected output.

Comment: It runs, but @EllaP clearly says that it doesn't do what expected sometimes.

Comment: If you see the answers below with the fix, it clearly does not always have the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routine was almost ok, here's a little comparison between yours, the fixed one and another possible solution to your problem:

```
def buggy(s):
    letter = s[0]
    best = ''
    for n in range(1, len(s)):
        if len(letter) > len(best):
            best = letter
        if s[n] >= s[n - 1]:
            letter += s[n]
        else:
            letter = s[n]

    return best


def fixed(s):
    letter = s[0]
    best = ''
    for n in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[n] >= s[n - 1]:
            letter += s[n]
        else:
            letter = s[n]

        if len(letter) > len(best):
            best = letter

    return best


def alternative(s):
    result = ['' for i in range(len(s))]
    index = 0

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if (i == len(s) - 1 and s[i] >= s[i - 1]) or s[i] <= s[i + 1]:
            result[index] += s[i]
        else:
            result[index] += s[i]
            index += 1

    return max(result, key=len)


for sample in ['maezsibmhzxhpprvx', 'ysdxvkctcpxidnvaepz']:
    o1, o2, o3 = buggy(sample), fixed(sample), alternative(sample)
    print "buggy={0:10} fixed={1:10} alternative={2:10}".format(o1, o2, o3)
```

As you can see in your version the order of the inner loop conditional is not good, you should move the first conditional to the end of loop.

Answer (score 3):

You should move this check

```
if len(letter) > len(best):
    best = letter
```

after the rest of the loop

Answer (score 1):

The logic is almost okay except that if `letter` grows on the last loop iteration (when `n == len(s) - 1`), `best` is not changed that last time. You may insert another `best = letter` part after the loop, or re-think carefully the program structure so you won't repeat yourself.

Comment: Moreover, you may want to consider the case where you have multiple longest alphabetical substrings...do you just want to select the first one you come across? It would really depend on what your application of this is, but worth considering how you want to handle that situation.

Comment: Absolutely. And on top of that, I re-read the question and I just thought that the program doesn't actually care how alphabetical the substring is.